# Linq to SQL valid Contacts in each Customer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I need to return all customers with all valid contacts:

Contact Class:

```
public class Contact
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
}
```

Customer Class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

List of Customers:

```
List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>
{
   new Customer
   {
       ID = 1,
       Name = "Ahmed",
       Contacts = new List<Contact>
       {
           new Contact { ID = 1 , Name = "A", IsValid = true },
           new Contact { ID = 2 , Name = "B", IsValid = true },
           new Contact { ID = 3 , Name = "C", IsValid = true }
       }
   },
   new Customer
   {
       ID = 2,
       Name = "Mohamed",
       Contacts = new List<Contact>
       {
           new Contact { ID = 4 , Name = "D", IsValid = true },
           new Contact { ID = 5 , Name = "E", IsValid = true },
           new Contact { ID = 6 , Name = "F", IsValid = false }
       }
   },
   new Customer
   {
       ID = 3,
       Name = "Ali",
       Contacts = new List<Contact>
       {
           new Contact { ID = 7 , Name = "X", IsValid = false },
           new Contact { ID = 8 , Name = "Y", IsValid = false },
           new Contact { ID = 9 , Name = "Z", IsValid = false }
       }
   }
};
```

Result needed after apply LINQ:

```
List<Customer> customersResult = new List<Customer>
            {
                new Customer
                {
                    ID = 1,
                    Name = "Ahmed",
                    Contacts = new List<Contact>
                    {
                        new Contact { ID = 1 , Name = "A", IsValid = true },
                        new Contact { ID = 2 , Name = "B", IsValid = true },
                        new Contact { ID = 3 , Name = "C", IsValid = true }
                    }
                },
                new Customer
                {
                    ID = 2,
                    Name = "Mohamed",
                    Contacts = new List<Contact>
                    {
                        new Contact { ID = 4 , Name = "D", IsValid = true },
                        new Contact { ID = 5 , Name = "E", IsValid = true }
                    }
                },
                new Customer
                {
                    ID = 3,
                    Name = "Ali",
                    Contacts = new List<Contact>()
                }
            };
```

i need to return each customer and each customer contains only IsValid = true Contacts, mains that the customer not contains IsValid Contacts Display without Contacts, How can do that by LINQ?

Comment: can you provide a sample of what you have tried so far?

Comment: List<Customer> customersResult = customers.Where(c=>c.Contacts.Any(cc=>cc.IsValid)).ToList();

but not working, this return all cutomers that there have valid contacts and try the below code but it's fire exception 

List<Customer> customersResult = customers.Include(c => c.Contacts.Where(cc => cc.IsValid)).ToList();

Comment: Please edit your original post to include the code you tried. Please add the exception that occurs with your other attempt.

Comment: Also, if `Customer` is an Entity from LINQ to Entities, you can't modify the contents of `Contacts` from what is returned by the database, you need a new object that isn't part of the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Customer> customersResult = customers.Select(x => new Customer {
    ID = x.ID,
    Name = x.Name,
    Contacts = x.Contacts?.Where(c => c.IsValid).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

Comment: I try to do that but not working and fire the below exception:

Message = "The entity or complex type 'ConsoleApp.Customer' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query."

Comment: Oh you're using Entity Framework @MohamedZanoon? That changes everything, my answer is for Linq to Objects